# symfony2: How to access a different entity manager in security user provider

Tags: php, security, symfony

How can I access two entity managers in the security user provider class in Symfony2?

Purpose: The app needs to access to two databases. One is for loading the security user and another is to create an entry of the user.

Current situation: only the entity manager is used. I am injecting another entity manager. However, the default entity manager that is configured in the "providers" of security.yml is used. When I uncomment this then default_manager is used. In any case, only one entity manager is used.

Security.yml:

```
providers:
    main:
        entity:
            class: Entity\sm\UserPro
            property: apiKey
            manager_name: userpro_manager
```

Security user provider:

```
class UserProviderMP implements AuthenticationProviderInterface{
public function __construct(
    UserProviderInterface $userProvider,
    EntityManagerFactory $entityManagerFactory)`
```

I am using `entitymanagerfactory` to get access to another entity manager:

`$this->entityManagerFactory->getentityManager();`

How can I access a different entity manager other than the entity manager configured in security.yml?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no issue in my code. There is a wrapper class that always returns the same entity manager instead of the entity manager that the code is asking for while running my tests. I have disabled this wrapper class and it works perfectly fine.

Thanks!!!